# How to remove all but emojis in a (Javascript) string?

Tags: javascript, regex, emoji

I'm trying multiple regex expressions but I cannot get them to work.

I have a simple input where the users can type whatever they like, only that the final result must contain emojis. To achieve this, I have to remove every character from the string which is not an emoji, and then check if the length is >= 1.

So basically this: `asf..?23kjgasdf..,fwe34` should become this: . Then I'd check the length to confirm that it's >=1 and I'd be good to go.

I'm usign Mac OS very own virtual emoji keyboard to write the emojis along the text in the input, in case you find it useful to know.

Comment: Add the code you've already attempted to your question.

Comment: `"I'm trying multiple regex expressions"` - and have posted none? what does an emoji look like in a javascript string?

Comment: It shows like just an icon, although it has attached a unicode internally (http://apps.timwhitlock.info/emoji/tables/unicode).

Comment: I'm just using the "replace" function to remove the chars, something like `tags.replace(/^[\u1f600-\u1f64f]/g, 'X');`, which instead of removing the characters should change them for an 'X'.

Comment: What about `.replace(/\ud83d[\ude00-\ude4f]/g, '')` to remove all emojis, and then count `s.length - s_new.length`?

Comment: Again, _please post the code you've already tried_.

Comment: Problem is, I need to update the resulting emojis (the string without any other character along, just the icons) to a database.

Comment: There must be a regex that does the opposite of `.replace(/\ud83d[\ude00-\ude4f]/g, '')`. I read about the `^` modifier but cannot get it to work...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From what I get from comments, some of this may or may not help -

---

---

To validate a string contains 1 or more emoji :

```
 # ^(?=[\S\s]*(?:\ud83d[\ude00-\ude4f]))

 ^ 
 (?=
      [\S\s]* 
      (?: \ud83d [\ude00-\ude4f] )
 )
```

---

---

To remove only emoji, leaving the rest (global) :

Find: `(?:\ud83d[\ude00-\ude4f])*((?:(?!\ud83d[\ude00-\ude4f])[\S\s])+)(?:\ud83d[\ude00-\ude4f])*`
Replace:  `$1`

```
 (?: \ud83d [\ude00-\ude4f] )*
 (                                       # (1 start)
      (?:
           (?! \ud83d [\ude00-\ude4f] )
           [\S\s] 
      )+
 )                                       # (1 end)
 (?: \ud83d [\ude00-\ude4f] )*
```

---

---

To remove everything but emoji (global) :

Find: `((?:\ud83d[\ude00-\ude4f])*)(?:(?!\ud83d[\ude00-\ude4f])[\S\s])+((?:\ud83d[\ude00-\ude4f])*)`
Replace:  `$1$2`

```
 (                                       # (1 start)
      (?: \ud83d [\ude00-\ude4f] )*
 )                                       # (1 end)
 (?:
      (?! \ud83d [\ude00-\ude4f] )
      [\S\s] 
 )+
 (                                       # (2 start)
      (?: \ud83d [\ude00-\ude4f] )*
 )                                       # (2 end)
```

---

***edit**: To use different emoji utf16 ranges do this*

Different high surrogates:

```
(?:
     High_surrogate_A [Low_surrogate_start_A-Low_surrogate_end_A]
  |  High_surrogate_B [Low_surrogate_start_B-Low_surrogate_end_B]
  |  High_surrogate_C [Low_surrogate_start_C-Low_surrogate_end_C]
)
```

or, same high surrogate, different low surrogate ranges:

```
(?:
     High_surrogate [Low_surrogate_start1-Low_surrogate_end1Low_surrogate_start2-Low_surrogate_end2]
)
```

or, mix:

```
(?:
     High_surrogate_A [Low_surrogate_startA1-Low_surrogate_endA1Low_surrogate_startA2-Low_surrogate_endA2]
  |  High_surrogate_B [Low_surrogate_start_B-Low_surrogate_end_B]
)
```

Where you see:

`(?: \ud83d [\ude00-\ude4f] )*`

substitue one of the above in placeholder `HERE`

`HERE`*

Where you see:

`(?! \ud83d [\ude00-\ude4f] )`

substitue one of the above in placeholder `HERE`

(?! `HERE` )

---

*Note- you can add a High-surrogate range as well, however all the high surrogates must share the same low-surrogate(s) range.*

Comment: This works almost fine, but it's mostly due to new emojis being added in other UTF ranges, so they are removed when they shouldn't be. This code works basically fine, but as I say it removes more than it should. How can I add more ranges so the new emojis doesn't get removed? And where did you find those ranges, by the way, if you can tell me.

Answer (score 0):

Emojis are in a supplemental plane, at 1F601 - 1F64F. Normal JS regexps do not work (well) with such code points. If you have available an ES6 implementation which supports the new `u` flag (Babel does), that should do the job for you.

```
tags.replace(/^[\u{1f600}-\u{1f64f}]/g, 'X');
```

Otherwise, you need to consider using a library such as https://github.com/mathiasbynens/regenerate.